# How can I render PDF file pages as images?

Tags: pdf, c#-2.0

I need to be able to convert a PDF file to images (one image per page) to be displayed on a web page like Google Docs does. This is for an internal intranet application where the requirements call for a PDF file on the web but with the ability to track scrolling, and this is the only way I can come up with to do it.

The problem is I can't find a *good* way to convert PDF files on the fly.

Comment: Good = a .net component that does it and allows me to .Save an image... no print drivers or anything like that

Comment: .NET's document model is built around Microsoft's hubris to kill off PDF with XPS. So your chances of doing it without third-party tools is small.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [GhostScript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/).  It's open source and can by run as a command line process or directly through the DLL.  I've used this in a production app for the last 2 years with minimal problems.

To see how to export images using the dll directly, see [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GhostScriptUseWithCSharp.aspx).

Comment: I am seriously hoping to get away without having to run something in a seperate process.

Comment: Actually it looks like you can call the dll directly, but I can't get very high quality images for some reason :(

Comment: It must be some sort of DPI flag.  I wasn't actually aware you could call the dll directly.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Just had to bump up the ResolutionXY and now I've got high quality images... works great :)

Comment: Is it possible to get pages count in PDF using GhostScript Library?

Comment: Today (2016), Ghostscript is (for a while), AGPL. [IANAL !!!] This means at least you cannot link against the lib without getting "license-infected". Consult your lawyer, the Affero variant tries to infect you [your code's license] by the fact that the output is used in commercial setting [so even requiring user to download Ghostscript excecutable - which your program will launch - might require license change]. Of course, they have commercial license ;-)))

Answer (score 2):

We use [ABCpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) here to convert PDFs to images.

Note: it is NOT free

Answer (score 1):

You can use ImageMagik, it's free and can do that kind of conversion.

http://www.imagemagick.org

Comment: ImageMagick requires GhostScript to do the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Try the PDF components from [Tall Components](http://tallcomponents.com/) to convert to images.

You will need to look into these a bit further to track changes etc and may require converting to text.

Answer (score 0):

### PeaPDF

I created a free open source project for rendering PDFs - https://github.com/elicym/peapdf/.

### Ghostscript

You can also use [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com), but its license is AGPL, and you will likely need to distribute your code if you use it. See https://www.ghostscript.com/license.html, especially the part:

> Bottom line, if you distribute our software, or make the functionality of the software available to users interacting with it remotely through a computer network, you must share your source code.